# Is there any difference between Intel T7300 and T7250

Tags: cpu

Is there any performance difference between

Intel® Core™2 Duo Processor T7250

and

Intel® Core™2 Duo Processor T7300?

Both has 2.00GHz clock speed.

Comment: http://ark.intel.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

T7250 has a 2Mb L2 Cache whereas T7300 has a 4Mb

Comment: How much does it affect the performance?

Comment: The more cache you have, the faster math and other things can be done. Cache stores the most frequently used instructions to save time. In everyday work, there will be no noticeable difference. If you are doing a lot of number crunching, the extra cache might come into play. This comment taken from here http://forum.notebookreview.com/hardware-components-aftermarket-upgrades/83613-2mb-cache-vs-4mb-cache.html